# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set Java JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a person table and an Email table in my sql database, the email table and person table are both connected via a "personId" So in this block of code I want to get the email from a specific personId that should be reading in from my SQL database. But the issue is my program is not updating the "?" to a personId. When I remove "where personId = ?;" my code works fine but I get every single email from the table if anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

```
String query = "Select * from Person;";
        String emailQ = "Select Email.email from Email where personId = ?;";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        ResultSet rs = null;

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        rs = ps.executeQuery(); 

        
        try(PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(emailQ);) {
            pstmt.setInt(1, rs.getInt("personId"));
            ResultSet rs2 = pstmt.executeQuery();
        
          while (rs2.next()) {
                String email = rs2.getString("email");
                emails.add(email);
            }
        }


        while (rs.next()) {
            int i = 1;

            int personId = rs.getInt("personId");
            System.out.println(personId);
            String firstname = rs.getString("firstname");
            String lastname = rs.getString("lastname");
            String type = rs.getString("type");
            String userName = rs.getString("username");
            String password = rs.getString("password");
            Person a = new Person(personId, firstname, lastname, type, userName, password, emails);
            persons.put(i, a);
            i++;
        }
```

Program fails at line

```
pstmt.setInt(1, rs.getInt("personId"));
```

Comment: `String query = "SELECT Person.*, Email.email FROM Person JOIN ON Email WHERE Person.personId = Email.personId";` -- A basic JOIN should make your life a lot easier.

Comment: `pstmt.setInt(1, rs.getInt("personId"));` <- `rs.getInt` is been called before you position the cursor (this is what `rs.next()` will do - if there is a row of data), but what Elliott said

Comment: Thank you I didn't of using a Join it works perfectly now.